# NLP various probabilities estimators in nltk

Tags: python, natural-language, nltk, entropy

I saw there are many types of probabilities in nltk:
MLE, ELE, Laplace, Heldout, KnereserNey, Lidstone, Random, WittenBel..
What is the exact difference between them and when should I use each?

My goal is to get the entropy of a specific sentence from the vector of probabilities.

For example, once trained on a specific model, I want to compare the entropy of "The computer is on the desk" and "The pen is black and old", to know which one is more likely.

Thanks!

Comment: @KenHBS Sure, editted

Comment: So you already have the vector of probabilities for each of those models, and you want to compute the entropy for a specific set of tokens? you can compute it with Shannon's measure of entropy H(Sentence) = - sum( P(token_i) * log( P(token_i) ) ) for i in n, where n is the number of tokens in the sentence. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition)

Comment: @DanielR. No, I am familiar with how to measure entropy - I want to know which of the aforementioned modules is the best for my case to get vector of probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Since you are interested in the entropy (or perplexity) of a sentence, I would definitely prefer the `KneserNeyProbDist` since it is especially designed for N-gram smoothing.

## Their differences

All the probability models you mentioned here is to estimate a probability distribution given a sample of data, represented by a counter (or a histogram) class called `FreqDist`. Their key differences are about how to do *smoothing*, i.e. how to account for *unseen* data. This is important in NLP because of the many distributions follow the [Zipf's law](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/zipfs-law-modeling-the-distribution-of-terms-1.html), and out-of-vocabulary word / n-gram constantly appears.

You can easily find how those methods do smoothing from their [documentation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html). For easy reference, see below. The first group of distributions are similar:

- `MLEProbDist`: basically no smoothing, just do a MLE estimation, resulting in the empirical distribution. Unseen words are assigned probability 0.
- `ELEProbDist`: adding 0.5 to all counts (including those possibly unseen words, whose original count is 0), then MLE.
- `LaplaceProbDist`: adding 1 to all counts, then MLE
- `LidstoneProbDist`: adding `gamma` to all counts, then MLE. For instanc if you specify `gamma=1` then the result is same as `LaplaceProbDist`.

The different ones are:

- `WittenBellProbDist`: You need to specify how many possible words/data types by `bins`, even though not all those words/data types appear in the corpus
- `RandomProbDist`: just random, nothing interesting.
- `HeldoutProbDist`: you need two counters (`FreqDist`s). I don't know what it does exactly.

#### Example with unigrams

Consider the following sentence:

```
"I like python but I do n\'t like java . John like c but he does n\'t like java . "
```

Based on the sentence above, we use the different models to estimate for the following three tokens: `I`, `python` and `c++`. (Note that `c++` does not appear in the training sentence above.)

```
UNIGRAM:            I       python  c++
frequency:          2       1       0
empirical:          0.095   0.048   0.000
-----------------------------------------
MLE                 0.095   0.048   0.000
ELE                 0.091   0.055   0.018
Laplace             0.088   0.059   0.029
Lidstone(gamma=1)   0.088   0.059   0.029
Lidstone(gamma=2)   0.085   0.064   0.043
WittenBell(bins=20) 0.059   0.029   0.055
```

#### The best one for your purpose

For the above ones, you can choose what to count in the `FreqDist`, either tokens (a.k.a. unigrams, as the example above), or bigrams or trigrams. The exception is `KneserNeyProbDist`, which only accepts trigrams:

- `KneserNeyProbDist`: use [Kneser–Ney smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Ney_smoothing), almost the best-performing technique for n-gram smoothing. For more details see [this tutorial](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf).

In my opinion, as long as you have a large corpus, the `KneserNeyProbDist` should be the way to go. Modeling a sentence as trigrams should be more meaningful than just unigrams, and `KneserNeyProbDist` is more suitable for trigrams and usually achieves much lower perplexity than unigram models.

Comment: do you think this method is better then get probabilities using RNN/LSTM model?

Comment: @okuoub No, If you mean "probabilities" as in language modeling, then RNN-based model is better than ngram based ones.